# Are there critical points in ecosystems?

Tags: ecosystem

Some days ago, I was thinking (partially) about the complex balance that is needed for an ecosystem to exist. I got curious about the existence of some sort of critical point, something - that when taken out of the system - makes life vanish.

Is there a single species that when took out of one ecosystem destroys the life in it? Perhaps there's not a single species, perhaps there could be a minimal set of species in which this could happen.

Excuse me for the poorly formulated question. I'm not a biology student, I just get random curiosities from time to time.

Comment: You will definitely be interested in reading on the concept of [ecosystem resilience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resilience_(ecology))

Comment: Another (overlapping) interesting place to look: the concept of keystone species.